# R date-time conversion time zones

Tags: r

I stumbled on an issue in the conversion of time to date:

```
times <- c("1976-05-01 01:00:00", "1977-05-01 01:00:00")
times2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(times, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="CET" ))
data.frame(times, times2, as.Date(times2), as.Date(times2, tz="CET"))
```

What I get on my R (*) is:

```
1976-05-01 01:00:00   1976-05-01   1976-05-01
1977-05-01 01:00:00   1977-04-30   1977-05-01
```

I know that timezones and conversions can be a real pain. It is so easy to forget tz="CET" in as.Date.

What are good strategies to NOT miss such an error? (I only caught it because merging with another May dataset yielded NAs).

BONUS: Why does the conversion with default tz change after 1977?

(*): sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting first before converting often solves this type of problem and also lets you check that `times2ch` is giving what you intend:

```
times2ch <- format(times2)
as.Date(times2ch)
## [1] "1976-05-01" "1977-05-01"
```

See the Help Desk article in [R News 4/1](https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

After scouring SO and looking for an answer, I just started using lubridate and force_tz().

As a bonus, lubridate's mdy_hms() is an order of magnitude faster than the base R strptime and similar. Very helpful when dealing with 10s of millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you check when they started using DST for CET, you will find that until 1976, no DST was used, 
check this link for example, to see when DST started check here
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/belgium/brussels
and find the years 1970-1980.